# will `grep -r /` avoid /dev/urandom & co?

Tags: linux, grep

(not sure if this question belongs on superuser or unix.stackexchange, if i'm in the wrong place, please let me know)

as the title says, is `grep -r / -e foo` going to avoid /dev/urandom /dev/zero /dev/random etc? or is it really going to `search through all of /dev/urandom`  ? (which would take practically forever and yield no interesting results)

Comment: I don't know, `grep /dev/random -e "To be or not to be"` sounds like it could result in something interesting after some time...

Answer (score 2):

`grep` will dive into infinite data sources such as `/dev/urandom` or `/dev/zero` by default. You can prevent this behavior by adding `-I`. Description from the manual:

> `-I`     Process a binary file as if it did not contain matching data; this is equivalent to the `--binary-files=without-match` option.

Comment: i don't want to skip binary files though, seems another option is `--devices=skip`

Comment: neither option (neither -I nor --devices=skip) prevents grep -r from getting hung on trying to read /dev/kmsg though =/ it doesn't get to read anything and just hangs on a read()